# Equivalent definitions for simple connectivity

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory, connectedness, fundamental-groups, path-connected

> For a path connected space $X$, it is simply connected iff any two paths sharing endpoints are homotopically equivalent. Here simple connectivity means it has trivial fundamental group.

I'm doing the if part, so let's suppose $X$ is path connected with equivalence property. Now given $a\in X$, I wish to show $\pi_1(X,a)=1$. Let $f\in\Omega(X,a)$, now if $f$ consists solely of a single point we are happy, if it contains another point say $b\ne a$, then we can split $f$ into two consecutive paths $g,h$ such that $h$ follows $g$ and $f=g*h$ (note: path multiplications are to be read from left to right, unlike ordinary map composites). Now, I have $h=g^-$, so, up to path homotopy, we have 
$$[f]=[g][h]=[g*g^-]. $$
Now I can't figure out how to show $g*g^-$ is equivalent to the constant path at $a$, although it is intuitively evident. Also for the converse question: if $[g*h]=[c]$ ($c$ means constant path) then how to prove $h\sim g^-$, I completely have no clue either. Intuition doesn't get me anywhere.

Silly as the two questions may look, could anyone enlighten me on them? Best regards to you!

Comment: At time t going to the point $g(1-t)$ from there point a and come back to the point a... This will be your homotopy map

Comment: @Anubhav.K I'm a bit confused about your description. It looks more like a path than a homotopy. Could you please be more specific? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I'm typing from mobile.. so I cannot write it mathematically ... I hope some one quickly give you a full description.

Comment: @Anubhav.K no problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should answer your question unless I made a mistake (it's sketchy in a couple places), and is probably a bit overkill but it clarifies some relevant concepts:

Let $X$ be path-connected, let $a,b\in X$, and let $\Omega_{[a,b]}(X)$ denote the space (with the compact-open topology) of continuous paths $\gamma\colon [0,1]\to X$ such that $\gamma(0)=a$ and $\gamma(1)=b$.  If $\gamma, \gamma'\in\Omega_{[a,b]}(X)$, then a path in this space from $\gamma$ to $\gamma'$ is nothing more than a "homotopy relative endpoints", that is a continuous function
$$H\colon [0,1]\times [0,1]\to X$$
such that $H(t,0)=\gamma(t)$, $H(t,1)=\gamma'(t)$, and $\forall s\ H(0,s)=a$ and $H(1,s)=b$; a homotopy relative endpoints will be denoted $H\colon \gamma\sim_{\{0,1\}}\gamma'$.  Define the space of loops based at $a$ as $\Omega_a(X)=\Omega_{[a,a]}(X)$; by definition $\pi_1(X;a)=\pi_0\Omega_a(X)$.

Lemma: for any $a,b\in X$ there is a bijection $\pi_0\Omega_{[a,b]}(X)\cong \pi_0\Omega_a(X)$

Proof: Since $X$ is path connected, we can choose a path $\rho$ in $X$ from $b$ back to $a$.  Now define the function $$\rho_*\colon\pi_0\Omega_{[a,b]}(X)\to \pi_0\Omega_a(X)$$
by $\rho_*([\gamma])=[\gamma\cdot\rho]$, where $\cdot$ is concatenation of paths from left to right.  Then:

1) It is a standard fact that concatenation of paths is well-defined up to homotopy relative end-points, so $\rho_*$ is a well-defined function.

2) $\rho_*$ is surjective: given a loop $\lambda$ in $X$ based at $a$, it is homotopic relative endpoints to the loop $$\lambda\cdot\rho^{-1}\cdot\rho$$ which represents the homotopy class $\rho_*([\lambda\cdot \rho^{-1}])$.

3) $\rho_*$ is injective: Suppose $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ are two paths from $a$ to $b$, and suppose there is a homotopy relative endpoints $$H\colon\gamma\cdot\rho\sim_{\{0,1\}}\gamma'\cdot\rho$$  By the definition of path concatenation, if $t\geq\frac{1}{2}$ then $H(t,0)=H(t,1)=\rho(2t-1)$.
Subclaim: $H$ can be made into a homotopy $H'\colon \gamma\cdot\rho\sim_{\{0,1\}}\gamma'\cdot\rho$ so that $\forall s$ and $\forall t\geq \frac{1}{2}$ we have $H'(t,s)=\rho(2t-1)$
(I leave it as an exercise to verify this claim because writing down a proof takes a bit of space).  Then $H'|_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]\times [0,1]}$ produces a homotopy between $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ relative endpoints.

Corollary: if $X$ is a path-connected space and $a\in X$, then $\pi_1(X;a)=1$ if and only if for any $b\in X$ and any two paths $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ from $a$ to $b$, there is a homotopy relative endpoints $H\colon\gamma\sim_{\{0,1\}}\gamma'$.

(Warning: this bijection is NON-canonical.  We had to CHOOSE the path $\rho$ from $b$ back to $a$, and non-homotopic choices of $\rho$ give different bijections.)